# Web API Methods: Return IHttpActionResult Or IQueryable

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I see most comments about Web API methods say they should return IHttpActionResult.  When I add a Controller in Visual Studio and I select "Web API 2 Controller With Action For Entity Framework" it entered these two methods (along with POST, PUT, and DELETE).  It uses IQueryable to return multiple records instead of IHttpActionResult.  Which is correct and why?

```js
        // GET: api/Trades
        public IQueryable<Trade> GetTrades()
        {
            return db.Trades;
        }

        // GET: api/Trades/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(Trade))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetTrade(int id)
        {
            Trade trade = db.Trades.Find(id);
            if (trade == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(trade);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either is correct. The convenience of `IQueryable` is that you, well, can query it.

For example: You can use OData with WebAPI where some flexibility is required. You can then make your AJAX requests like `mysite.com/odata/Orders?$filter=OrderID eq 1156`.

Here is more on OData: http://www.odata.org/

It proved to be very handy for a dynamic search API with pagination support.